# Foundation 5 - Fixed Position div pops out of grid

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've run into a problem with Foundation 5. If I want to use `position:fixed` on a `div` that is part of the Foundation Grid, it pops it out of the grid and aligns with the left edge of the row. Is there a work around for this?

```
 <div id="right" class="medium-4 columns show-for-medium-up" >
    <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
        <dd class="active"><a href="#recent">Recent</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#popular">Popular</a></dd>                         
    </dl>
    <div class="tabs-content">
        <div class="content active" id="recent">
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $query= new WP_Query();
                    $query->query(array('posts_per_page'=>10));
                    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>

                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- END .content -->
        <div class="content" id="popular">
            Popular posts
        </div>
    </div><!-- END .tabs-content -->
 </div><!-- END #right -->


 <script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
     var y = $(document).scrollTop(), right = $("#right");
     if(y >= 160)  {
         right.css({position: "fixed"});
     } else {
         right.css({position: "relative"});
     }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the code? did you put your columns inside div.row?

Comment: updated with full HTML code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to create a `sticky` top bar (Fixed Navigation or Contain to Grid), so when user scrolls bottom, the bar will display your recent and popular posts.

See how it should be done by reading the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html).

Comment: I already have a Magellan top bar, this is a side bar or recent articles.